# Zend Framework Composer Packages

Tags: php, zend-framework, package, composer-php

I would like to add dependency to `zendframework/zend-db` package, so I added it to my composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",

    "symfony/class-loader":  "dev-master",
    "symfony/console":       "dev-master",
    "symfony/filesystem":    "dev-master",
    "symfony/finder":        "dev-master",
    "symfony/locale":        "dev-master",
    "symfony/yaml":          "dev-master",
    "doctrine/dbal":         "dev-master",
    "zendframework/zend-db": "dev-master"
}
```

The problem is that composer installs entire `zendframework/zendframework` package.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [composer.json](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/composer.json) from zend-db in the zend github. According to the file, zend-db does not have any dependencies.

This can be due to the fact that you're trying to download a package from dev-master and there's a missmatch in the composer.json of the dev-master.

**I would suggest you to change the required version to something like 2.0.* and try again.**

---

Also, Although Zend Framework is loosely coupled, in the older versions of the framework the dependencies were not explicit.

For instance, with a quick sweep over the source code of zend_db from ZEND 1.9, I found that it depends, at least, on the following packages:

- Controller
- Config
- Filter
- Json
- Loader (for autoloading, I reckon this might not be necessary due to composer autoloader)
- Uri
- View
- Wildfire

These packages might have other dependencies, hence the download size. Regardless, as King explained, Zend Framework 2.0 is different from version 1.9 and maybe this is not applicable to 2.0

Comment: As far as I know only ZF2 is available via composer and the db-component were rewritten, thus the dependencies of the 1.9 are unimportant. And (regarding your edit): The linked `composer.json` sets the (self.)version to `2.0.*` (see the `branch_alias`-directive at the bottom)

Answer (score 11):

as explained here http://packages.zendframework.com/#composer ZF2 now provide a composer repository with all modules.

to add the repo to you package:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
    }
],
```

and from here on you can add packages seperately:

```
"require": {
    "zendframework/zend-config": "2.0.*",
    "zendframework/zend-http": "2.0.*"
},
```

you only need to specify the packages you want, if they have dependencies they will be resolved by compser.

allthough this does not seem to work atm...

Comment: @nicky-de-maeyer
Indeed. I have the repo in my json file and added only zend-db yet the whole framework is being pulled in. Is that what you meant when you said it isn't working at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if some packages have some php extensions in their dependencies. I have tried to install zend-http packages and have the same issue. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356318/install-component-zf2-using-composer) I've found suggestion to install php_intl extension because it is required by zend-validate - subdependancy of the zend-http package. Once I've added this extension to the php.ini - problem was solved.