# Is it normal that zendframework/zend-http package requires 49 components?

Tags: package, zend-framework2, composer-php

Here's the `composer.json`:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.zendframework.com/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zend-http": "2.*"
    }
}
```

... and the exhaustive list:

```
Authentication  Code     Db     Escaper       Filter  InputFilter  Log     Mime           Paginator    Server          Stdlib  Uri        XmlRpc
Barcode         Config   Debug  EventManager  Form    Json         Mail    ModuleManager  Permissions  ServiceManager  Tag     Validator
Cache           Console  Di     Feed          Http    Ldap         Math    Mvc            ProgressBar  Session         Test    Version
Captcha         Crypt    Dom    File          I18n    Loader       Memory  Navigation     Serializer   Soap            Text    View
```

Some of them actually make sense. But what about `Barcode`,`Captcha`,`Navigation` or even `Db`for instance?

**Edit**

```
$ rm -rf vendor
$ rm -rf ~/.composer/
$ rm composer.lock 
$ more composer.json 
{
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zend-http": "2.*"
    }
}
$ composer self-update
You are using the latest composer version.
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies
  - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.1.3)
    Downloading: 100%

zendframework/zendframework suggests installing doctrine/common (Doctrine\Common >=2.1 for annotation features)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ext-intl (ext/intl for i18n features)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing pecl-weakref (Implementation of weak references for Zend\Stdlib\CallbackHandler)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendpdf (ZendPdf for creating PDF representations of barcodes)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha (ZendService\ReCaptcha for rendering ReCaptchas in Zend\Captcha and/or Zend\Form)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

PS: pleased that some consider my question as simply good to be closed ... I really thank the others for having tryed to answer.

Comment: It's not normal, but on my system composer also installs the entire zendframework/zendframework package.  This seems to be an issue some are experiencing.  See [here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Framework-Composer-Pakages-td4656012.html), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747962/zend-framework-composer-packages), and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/composer-dev/yT33S9A9x1o).  I've also found more people with the issue through searches but haven't seen a solution. One said installing the intl extension fixed it but I did not try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't.

Using that composer.json file, I get this:

```
$ composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies
  - Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (2.1.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-servicemanager (2.1.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-filter (2.1.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-i18n (2.1.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-validator (2.1.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-escaper (2.1.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-uri (2.1.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-loader (2.1.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-http (2.1.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

zendframework/zend-stdlib suggests installing pecl-weakref (Implementation of weak references for Stdlib\CallbackHandler)
zendframework/zend-servicemanager suggests installing zendframework/zend-di (Zend\Di component)
zendframework/zend-filter suggests installing zendframework/zend-crypt (Zend\Crypt component)
zendframework/zend-validator suggests installing zendframework/zend-db (Zend\Db component)
zendframework/zend-validator suggests installing zendframework/zend-math (Zend\Math component)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

The full list of dependencies that `zend-http` has are:

- Escaper
- Filter
- i18n
- Loader
- ServiceManager
- StdLib
- Uri
- Validator

Comment: @davidloubere also to be noted that you don't need to add `packages.zendframework.com` to the repositories :)

Comment: @Ocramius I know but reading the instructions on `packages.zendframework.com`, I thought it would be better to follow them, namely adding the ZF composer repository. Just to mention, the same issue still occurs if I remove the reference to it from the `composer.json` (I'm on Ubuntu 11.04).

Comment: @davidloubere are you using the latest composer version?